# How to initiate python program with a change in the input?

Tags: python, user-input

I have an application made in python, this application takes input from a separate text file called input.txt, i have to design the application in such a way that application runs automatically with any input to input.txt. Such that i need not go to command prompt and run the program, if i give the input, or change the text present in input.txt, python program should start execute automatically.

Please help me out with this :)

Thank you :) :)

Comment: There is no platform-independent solution to this problem.  What platform are you on?

Comment: haha :D :D Jathanism, working on the project bro :-/ not able to figure this out :( 

@Sven Ubuntu, using python2.6

Comment: @Bhuvan: On Linux, you probably want to use "inotify". https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki

Comment: @thomas thanks for the link, i'm looking over the link, by the way please put this one in answer block, if it works i should be accepting this. By the way, if you have time can u please briefly tell how this works?

Comment: @Bhuvan: I've never used it myself, so I don't know much about it. I just know the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your program once and watch the filesystem changes for new or modified file. Try using python-inotify for linux:

https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify

Comment: sorry if you have time,can your briefly tell me how this one works?

Comment: @Bhuvan raj, i don't know how to use inotify either but examples on thats wiki page should be enough: https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki/List-of-Examples

Comment: i'm going through it, hope i get it work, once it's done will accept the answer for sure :) :)